# C++ Check if entire input is a float

Tags: c++, validation, input

So I'm trying to check my input for a valid input of 1 or 2. It works when I just enter a 3/4/5/6 or any character. But once I enter 1 or 2 anywhere in the input with some characters it skips straight through the check and continues on with the code.

So when I for example enter 1a, it chooses case 1 and keeps the a in the input buffer and messes up my code...

Also I want to run a check on other float-only inputs that can be about everything so I don't just want to check for 1 || 2

```
do
{
    while(!(cin >> iChoiceFile))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Please enter 1 or 2: ";
        cin >> iChoiceFile;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    switch(iChoiceFile)
    {
        case 1: makeNewFile();
            valid_answer = true;
            break;

        case 2: valid_answer = true;
            break;

        default: cout << "ERROR: Please enter 1 or 2: ";
            valid_answer = false;
            break;
    }

}while(!valid_answer);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what do you want to achieve? what is the problem? why do you put 1a while expecting 1 or 2?

Comment: Read input into a `string` or a `stringstream`, ensure that no characters are alphabetical or otherwise using the `cctype` library's `isalpha()` function. Use other functions from the library as needed (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/)

Comment: If you're checking for a floating point datatype, then a switch case statement is a poor choice.  Also your question makes me wonder if you really meant float and not integer.  What is the type of `iChoiceFile`?

Comment: What do you want to happen when they type "1a" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want is to check for an input for `1` or `2` as integers, not floats.

Try this instead:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

//...

string choice;
cout << "Enter a character: ";
getline(cin,choice);
while(!isdigit(choice[0]) || (choice[0] != '1' && choice[0] != '2')){
    cout << "\nERROR! Please enter 1 or 2 only!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a character: ";
    getline(cin,choice);
}
switch (atoi(&choice[0])){
    case 1: 
        makeNewFile();
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Functionality to execute when input is a 2" << endl;
        break;
}//no need for 'default'
```

Sample execution:

> Enter a character: 5 
>   ERROR! Please enter 1 or 2 only! 
>   Enter a character: a 
>   ERROR! Please enter 1 or 2 only! 
>   Enter a character: This is an entire weird string 
>   ERROR! Please enter 1 or 2 only! 
>   Enter a character: 1s 
>   makeNewFile();

We've successfully ignored all the characters after `1` in the last case.